# Get value of Web root

Tags: asp.net-core

On an ASP.NET Core Startup file I have the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {      
  services.AddMvc();
  services.AddPOLocalization(x => x.ResourcesPath = "wwwroot/assets"); 
}
```

How can get the value defined for web root instead of hard code it (wwwroot)?

Comment: have you found how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is an `IHostingEnvironment.WebRootPath` property:

> Gets or sets the absolute path to the directory that contains the web-servable application content files.

You can get instance from DI container:

```
private IHostingEnvironment _env; 

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
     // use env.WebRootPath here or variable in private field for future using
     // (like in ConfigureServices method)
     _env = env;
     ...
}


public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{      
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddPOLocalization(x => 
        x.ResourcesPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "assets")); 
}
```